# Images not resizing properly with "flex: shrink"

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

I've created a carousel of images inside of a flexbox, and given each of them a width of 200px. I'd like the images to resize at the same rate when I shrink the window, so I gave them each a flex-shrink value of 1.

However, as you can see from the gif, only the second image resizes when I shrink the window (the others stay the same width). I checked the original file sizes and noticed that the second image also has the smallest width (so I assume this could be causing the issue?)

However, I'm not exactly sure how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

**Html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>your page title goes here</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>My Photo Gallery</h1>
    <div class="gallery">
      <figure>
        <img src="img/dog1.jpeg" alt="first dog">
        <figcaption>Example Photo</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="img/dog2.jpeg" alt="second dog"/>
        <img src="img/dog3.jpeg" alt="third dog"/>
        <img src="img/dog4.jpeg" alt="fourth dog"/>
        <img src="img/dog5.jpeg" alt="fifth dog"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(46, 46, 46)
}

h1 {
  font-family: helvetica;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  padding: 30px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 1000px;
  min-width: 500px;
  background-color: rgb(66, 66, 66);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

figure {
  text-align: left;
}

figcaption {
  color: white;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.slider{
  margin-top: 32px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


.slider img {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why didnt you use the "height: auto;" property on the slider images?

Answer (score 0):

In this case if you don't want to add any extra markup just replace `width:200px;` in `.slider img` to `min-width:200px;`.

If you want to maintain a completely fluid layout you could replace `min-width:200px;` with something like `min-width:25%`.

As I mentioned in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69171768/img-doesnt-respect-width-in-html-with-flexbox/69171808#69171808) if you're willing to add a container to each of these images you'll have a bit more control as you can make the image expand to fill the container, regardless of what its dimensions are.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a media query

example:

```css
@media(max-width:700px){
.slider img {
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
} 
}
```